# How to understand "きざみ角煮{かくに}"

Tags: translation, food, renyōkei

In today's endeavour to augment my ability to read onigiri labels I came across this in Naha, Okinawa:

> きざみ角煮

Google Translate does a terrible job:

> Boiled angle increments

WWWJDIC has an entry for 角煮:

> stew of cubed meat or fish (esp. pork belly or tuna)

But I'm stumped by きざみ. Google thinks it means increment and WWWJIC has "shredded tobacco; notch; nick", which doesn't help much.

I've also tried Goo, Wikipedia, Wiktionary. I wonder if there's a wiki or other resource specializing in Japanese food terminology as this is a particular interest of mine.

Comment: 刻む (きざむ）means "to mince", so that should probably clear things up a bit.

Comment: きざみ角煮 is of the exact same structure we discussed here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/how-to-parse-%e3%81%82%e3%81%91%e3%81%90%e3%81%a1

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: Yes I was just coming to the same conclusion! It looks like I have to find a way to study this ～む → ～み thing. There seem to be many Japanese terms for "mince(d)" as adjective, noun, or verb. In dictionaries I've only found this as きざむ now that I know what to look for.

Comment: Do you still have a question? Do you want to write up an answer yourself?

Comment: @Earthliŋ: I think I have to properly learn this before I should go about writing up answers. After creating the new [tag:renyōkei] tag I see there are lots of questions on the topic, so I guess there's a fair bit to understand and I'm not alone (-: I'll certainly upvote and accept a good answer that makes the process in this instance nice and clear.

Comment: @hippietrail For verbs, the 連用形 is the form you use before the polite auxiliary 〜ます, so if you've learned how to make the polite form, you can make and recognize the 連用形 as well.  For example: `読む　→　読み　→　読みます` and `食べる　→　食べ　→　食べます`

Comment: I don't know if you're including Google Translate translations for humor reasons, but surely you must realize that it is inaccurate for almost anything you give it? I don't understand why you include it in your question.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie: Stack Exchange likes us to show that we tried to find answers before asking here. My experience is different to yours, I find it often gives helpful translations for very short inputs. But for a 5-character input this was not just inaccurate but terrible. To somebody with as little knowledge of Japanese as me I took this as a hint that it might not be the most straightforward 5 characters to translate for whatever reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

煮物 is a type of Japanese dish, which consists of food boiled in 出し (broth) and soy sauce, often with 料理酒 (cooking rice wine) and sugar.

The name of all types of 煮物 usually end with ～煮, e.g. 筑前煮, 粗煮, etc.

角煮 is a type of 煮物 with cubed meat or fish as main ingredient, similar in looks to meat stew.

刻む is one of the types of chopping food, which usually is done by chopping the food into strips (千切り) and then into tiny cubes.

きざみ角煮 is thus "minced stew". きざみ is the 連用形 form of the verb きざむ with joins to 角煮 to form a new word, as in 入り口, 出口 and thousands of other words. What's different is that this construction usually uses a 訓読み word, but here 角 is 音読み. This should cause no confusion as ～煮 is clearly a 訓読み suffix and 角煮 feels much like a 訓読み word. Besides, there are no other options: [刻角]{こっかく}煮 would sound like the filling is a type of 煮物 called 刻角煮.

Comment: Exemplary answer! どうもありがとうございます！